# Android gridview in fragment adapter constructor missing

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, adapter

I am trying to implement a grid of images. I have done that in an activity by referring to this [link.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html#example)
Now, if I try to implement the same thing in a class which extends Fragment, I have done this

```
package com.example.emergency1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView.FindListener;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class City1 extends Fragment {


    public static Fragment newInstance(Context context) {
        City1 f = new City1();
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.city1, null);
        GridView gv1=(GridView)getView().findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gv1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
        return root;
    }

}
```

and for the adapter

```
package com.example.emergency1;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context ctx;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c)
    {
        ctx=c;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return pics.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ImageView iv;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            iv = new ImageView(ctx);
            iv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(350,350));
            iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            iv.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            iv = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        iv.setImageResource(pics[position]);
        return iv;

    }

    private Integer[] pics={
            R.drawable.sample_0,R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2,R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4,R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6,R.drawable.sample_7
    };
    }
```

Here, I am getting an error on the line

`gv1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));`

As I do not have a corresponding constructor in the adapter class. How do I resolve this issue. Could you also redirect me to some link where I can learn more about how to implement activity UI elements in fragments?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
     gv1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity()));
```

instead of this

```
     gv1.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
```

You need to pass the activity context.

Also this

```
   GridView gv1=(GridView)getView().findViewById(R.id.gridview);
```

should be

```
   GridView gv1=(GridView)root.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
```

Comment: i have tried that but now my application crashes, showing nullpointer exception in this line `        GridView gv1=(GridView)getView().findViewById(R.id.gridview);
`