# Android ImageAdapter with Gridview in Fragment

Tags: java, android, gridview, adapter, baseadapter

I have an adapter with gridview that works as an Activity. I am trying to place it in a Fragment now and converted things but it does not work. When I include the IconFragmentSystem in my Activity I get a force close when I try to open the Activity.

I know the Activity works because I can use other Fragments and everything is okay so I know my issue lies within this file.

```
package com.designrifts.ultimatethemeui;
import com.designrifts.ultimatethemeui.R;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class IconFragmentSystem extends Fragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
private static final String RESULT_OK = null;
public Uri CONTENT_URI;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int iconSize=getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.app_icon_size);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.icon_grid);
    gridview.setAdapter(new IconAdapter(this, iconSize));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    CONTENT_URI=Uri.parse("content://"+iconsProvider.class.getCanonicalName());
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String icon=adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    Intent result = new Intent(null, Uri.withAppendedPath(CONTENT_URI,icon));
    setResult(RESULT_OK, result);
    finish();
}
private void setResult(String resultOk, Intent result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void finish() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
private class IconAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;
    private int mIconSize;
    public IconAdapter(Context mContext, int iconsize) {
        super();
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mIconSize = iconsize;
        loadIcon();
    }

    public IconAdapter(IconFragmentSystem iconssystem, int iconSize) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbs.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mThumbs.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(mIconSize, mIconSize));
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbs.get(position));
        return imageView;
    }

    private ArrayList<Integer> mThumbs;
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private void loadIcon() {
        mThumbs = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        final Resources resources = getResources();
        final String packageName = getActivity().getApplication().getPackageName();

        addIcon(resources, packageName, R.array.systemicons);

    }
    private void addIcon(Resources resources, String packageName, int list) {
        final String[] extras = resources.getStringArray(list);
        for (String extra : extras) {
            int res = resources.getIdentifier(extra, "drawable", packageName);
            if (res != 0) {
                final int thumbRes = resources.getIdentifier(extra,"drawable", packageName);
                if (thumbRes != 0) {
                    mThumbs.add(thumbRes);
                }
            }
            }
           }
        }
    }
```

I have tried different ways to implement this but all have failed and I could really use help pointing me in the right direction.

This is my xml in layout

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >           
  <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: What does the LogCat have to say about this?

Comment: @Ray Stojonic When I run logcat it gives me 'code'10-06 19:10:27.450: E/AndroidRuntime(10180): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-06 19:10:27.450: E/AndroidRuntime(10180): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-06 19:10:27.450: E/AndroidRuntime(10180):  at com.designrifts.ultimatethemeui.IconFragmentSystem.onCreateView(IconFragmentSystem.java:28)  So I know it is from the onCreateView. Ive looked at examples and read the Android site but haven't had any luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue

I changed

```
    GridView gridview = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.icon_grid);
```

to

```
    GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_grid);
```

and I also changed

```
     gridview.setAdapter(new IconAdapter(this, iconSize));
```

to

```
     gridview.setAdapter(new IconAdapter(getActivity(), iconSize));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,int pos, long l) {

                // do something...

            }               
        });
```

For more info, see this link:
[Android gridview in fragment adapter constructor missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17397590/android-gridview-in-fragment-adapter-constructor-missing?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

`GridView gridview = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.icon_grid);`

should be

`GridView gridview = (GridView) container.findViewById(R.id.icon_grid);`

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container, false);

    int iconSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(android.R.dimen.app_icon_size);

    GridView gridview = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_grid);
    gridview.setAdapter(new IconAdapter(this, iconSize));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://"+iconsProvider.class.getCanonicalName());
    return view;
}
```

Your going to want to remove the call to super, that is a leftover from you activity, the fragment does not call this method.

Comment: I still got the same error when I added that. I put the logcat up as well as the version of the code that works  http://pastebin.com/ByjyURxs is the logcat. This is the working version from Activity https://github.com/designrifts/Ultimate_Theme_UI_Template/blob/master/src/com/designrifts/ultimatethemeui/icons.java

Comment: Also do not call through to super in oncreateview

Comment: I did remove the super. Thanks!